# Why is such a low carb intake mandated for keto-adaptation?

Tags: diet, ketosis, keto-adaption

I see a lot of articles that suggest 10-50g carbs / day to get into ketosis.

Why so low?

I need at least 2500+ calories / day. Even if I consumed half of my calories from carbs and glycolysis supplied half of my requirements, the other half would have to come from ketosis, no? And if I spend half of every day in ketosis, won't I (slowly) become keto-adapted?